# Should I be worried about the settings table getting huge?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have got a pretty fat settings table in SQL Server 2012, now with over 100 columns. As the name suggests, this table keeps track of all kinds of setting values within our website. It used to be having less than 50 columns but now its size is doubled.

The reason why I store setting values into database is because users will need to have ability to change these settings via UI.

Should I really be worried about this table getting bigger and bigger over time? Or I will have to find some other ways to store settings data, e.g save into files, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to store settings in a database in order to update them at runtime by users.  You can simply store them in a settings file that gets updated whenever the user makes changes.  This is an xml config file and works well.

If, however, the application is network based, and you want the settings to follow the user from machine to machine, it makes more sense to put it in a database.

Second, yes... 100 columns is huge.  Instead of storing each setting in a separate column, you might consider storing each setting in a separate row, and then have a common row format which is ID, SettingName, SettingValue, (maybe) DefaultValue.  Then your table can grow as large as you like.

Answer (score 1):

We are using JSON to store user settings. The table obtains only two columns - the user Id and the setting string. This string is quite long, but it doesn't matter. You can also use XML to store this data.

This is worse solution to modify data by finger, but faster to get from your DB and process by the client or by the ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 1):

I am imagining that you are concerned about performance on huge tables?

One question is how many rows in this table? 100 columns with 10000 rows is not real problem. 100 columns over 10million rows is a slightly different ballgame. Not worse of better, just different.

The same considerations apply for small and large tables:
 1. Are you indexing properly
 2. Is your IO fine
 3. Is your space fine
 4. Are you querying efficiently

There is no right answer for this, it would depend of why you have big column counts and whether it's hitting your overall performance.
We run 1000s of tables with > 150 columns and no problems, even with millions of rows between them and I can't complain about performance.
And this is relatively de-normalized data, so lots of text.

Answer (score 0):

10 years later: My take on a settings table is to make it high, not wide. The benefits:

1. Get settings one by one on demand to make sure they are always fresh.  A wide table typically gets all settings at once.
2. You can add settings without modifying the table.

Drawbacks: If you store all settings as strings, you will have to cast them to the correct type. If you have a different column for each type, you will have a lot of empty columns.  For example, a string value will have an empty int value. As storage is cheap, and settings tables small anyways, I opt for the later.

Note that this is meant for volatile settings.  A setting which is retrieved often and is not volatile would be best in appSettings.json.